# Webkit Scrollbar Error

Tags: ios, webkit, scrollbar

I have a problem with my webkit scrollbar on the iPod/iPhone/iPad - the user can't scroll down. The scrollbar just looks like a floating line, and the page breaks halfway through. (It works fine in Chrome & Safari.)

Is there any way I can **keep** the scrollbar, but have it not be custom on apple products?

[Here's my site](http://epicjamess.tumblr.com/), and here's my scrollbar code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}


html {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


body {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    font-family: arial, serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
        color: #999;
}
```

Comment: Hi James.  I've edited your question to focus on the technical stuff (just the facts, ma'am).  If there's something that's missing, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to load that scrollbar styling code from a *separate* stylesheet. Move it over to a new file, lets say `scrollbars.css`, and attach this code to your JavaScript:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (userAgent.search('iphone') == -1 && userAgent.search('ipod') == -1)
{
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="scrollbars.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

---

In your site, you have these styles *in the main page*:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

...
```

Take them and copy them over to a *new* file called `scrollbars.css`. Now, *delete* those old ones from your site completely. The JavaScript loads the scrollbar CSS file automagically.

Comment: Thanks that works, but how do I make it so the regular iphone scrollbar shows?

Comment: You'd have to override and replace your first styles with the defaults. I'll try and see what they are (Chrome can give you those things). Make sure to put this CSS *last* in your stylesheet, as the last piece of CSS executed is the one which takes effect.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find the defaults.

Comment: Me either. The problem is simply the page gets cut in half, instead of being able to scroll... if I remove the scrollbar it SHOULD work, but I like the scrollbar... :(

Comment: I've added some JS.  You can *load* that stylesheet dynamically, first checking whether the browser is MobileSafari or not.

Comment: BTW, I'd accept the answers to your questions. When you don't, nobody will answer them (usually).

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on it now. But still, what should I put where it says "/* iPhone scrollbar overrides go here */", because the scrollbar is the main issue, & IDK what CSS to put there, to make it so its just the regular iPhone scrollbar.

Comment: Ignore that completely (and don't use that code at all). The JavaScript I posted doesn't *let* the iPhone browser load the stylesheet which changes the scrollbars (make sure to move all those related styles to `scrollbars.css`).

Comment: Now I'm confused... :( Do you have an iPod/apple product? If you do, load http://epicjamess.tumblr.com/ on it, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Sadly, I don't. Can you screenshot it (`Home` button + `Power` key saves it to your `Pictures` folder) and post it here (or link to it)? Or can you describe it?

Comment: http://i54.tinypic.com/izqa9f.png The scrollbar acts as if it was a div. Normally, you can just scroll down on the iPod, but since I have the styled scrollbar, you can't. I wanna know how I can remove the scrollbar, but ONLY on apple products.

Comment: iPhones shouldn't even be able to *see* the stylesheet with that code if you implemented my JavaScript correctly. Did you make sure to *remove* the link to the stylesheet from the site? My code loads the scrollbar stylesheet *only* if the browser isn't running on an iPhone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Mind posting the javascriptfor me?

Comment: I pasted the script in, & it made my blog a white page. O_O

Comment: Where did you paste it? And how does Tumblr organize it's files? Does it even let you upload custom files, or are you forced to write it all into a single file?

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the scroll bar. As good as it may look, if it doesnt work on the iphone it's not worth it. :/

Comment: Okay, it seems like you are. Get that separate `scrollbar.css` file uploaded somewhere, and modify my JS to point to it. **EDIT** oh well. That's why you use a *real* blogging engine ;)